# VAE intractable numerator and denominator

Tags: probability

I am trying to understand the variational autoencoder following the tutorial here. https://jaan.io/what-is-variational-autoencoder-vae-tutorial/ Below I write my explanation before asking the questions. Please do let me know if my explanations themselves are wrong.

**Explanation**

We write the joint probability of a variational autoencoder as $p(x,z) = p(x|z)p(z)$. In order to compute the expression, we must first sample from $p(z)$ (a gaussian distribution) before we feed it through the neural network to generate $p(x|z)$. But we do not know the parameters (mu and sigma) of $p(z)$ is so we must first **infer** the parameters of the gaussian distribution.

This is done by computing $p(z|x) = \frac{p(x|z)p(z)}{p(x)}$. (**)But the expression here is intractable because of the denominator $p(x)$ which requires us to marginalize over all possible configurations/parameters of the variable $z$.

**Question:**

Why is it intractable **only** because of the denominator $p(x)$? We do not know what $p(z)$ is right? So shouldn't the sentence at (**) instead be the following:

But the expression here is intractable because of the denominator $p(x)$ which requires us to marginalize over all possible configurations/parameters of the variable $z$ and because of the numerator $p(z)$ because we do not know what $p(z)$ is.